# How To Grab HTML From Page Mac Os Swift 3

Tags: swift

I would like to know why this is not working. Could someone share a better way to get information from a website. Here I'm trying to grab a price of and item from HomeDepot Website. Then display it in a label called lblmessage.

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.homedepot.com/p/SAKRETE-80-lb-Gray-Concrete-Mix-65200390/100350291?MERCH=REC-_-NavPLPHorizontal1_rr-_-NA-_-100350291-_-N")!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        var message = ""
        if error != nil {
            print(error)

        }else {
            if let unwrappedData = data {
                let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                var stringSeparator = "<span id=\"ajaxPriceAlt\" class=\"pReg\" itemprop=\"price\">"
                if let contentArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: stringSeparator) {
                    if contentArray.count > 0 {
                        stringSeparator = "</span>"
                        let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeparator)
                        if newContentArray.count > 0 {
                          message = newContentArray[0]

                            print(newContentArray[0])
                            self.lblmessage.stringValue = newContentArray[0]

                        }




                    }

                }




            }
        }
```

Comment: And what's not working? What's working? Where is your issue? Do you call `task.resume()`? You maybe want to assure to update UI (update of the label) in main thread.

Comment: I would add more logs for the `if let`s by adding `else` and see where the `if` conditions are not being met.